# I want to change the language of my references

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I'm writing my thesis in Dutch. In my references 'and' is used between two authors and I would like to use 'en' (the dutch word). I've already looked this up and tried to change it via the .bst file, but nothing is changing in my Latex file... Is there an other way to change it?

```
\documentclass[11.5pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption, setspace}
\usepackage{a4wide}   %text in the middle of the page
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
my text

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
{\fontsize{9pt}{1.2pt}\selectfont
\bibliography{library}}

\end{document}
```

If I change the .bst file (I called it apalike-dutch), I changed "and" two times to "en" in line 222 and 848 of the code. Then I saved it in the same place my other Latex files are and changed `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` to `\bibliographystyle{apalike-dutch}`. After running my code for a few times, nothing changed.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also, do you use the `babel` package?

Comment: The simplest way is with `biblatex`. Could you consider using it?

Comment: Welcome. Changing the bst file (as well as name, version, etc) should work fine if you did everything right. Modern package `biblatex` has support for different languages. You can have a look at [bibliographies with biblatex and biber](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber).

Comment: Time for spring cleaning: Please don't load the same package multiple times.

Comment: which packages are the same? (I used a template of a student of last year, so for some packages, I don't know what they stand for)

Comment: Off-topic: Try commenting out all packages you don't know what they stand for should help you to find out whether or not you need them. At the end, remove all not needed packages. Not using a template but beginning from scratch and adding only those packages you need (and read at least parts of the manual) would be another suggestion. There are several strange packages/settings in the example above, e.g., modern editors use `utf8` as default, `fixltx2e` is not required with LaTeX after 2015 (and usually warns about this), better use `geometry` than `a4wide` …

Comment: I clean up my packages.

Comment: @Elise `graphicx` is loaded twice, I did not look if there are more.

Comment: @Moriambar Yes I use the `babel` package

Comment: @Elise But back to you question: Can you try a few things? Change `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` to `\bibliographystyle{apalike-dutch}`, delete all the auxillary files created by tex (just keep your .tex file and .bib file) and then compile again with `pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex`. Does it work or do you get any errors or warnings? if this did not help, place  `apalike-dutch.bst` in the same folder as your .tex file and do the steps of this comment again.

Comment: @samcarter: It works! Thank you so much!!!! :)

Answer (score 3):

To use your adapted bibliography style change the following line

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

to

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike-dutch}
```